# putting job into foreground shell implemented c

Tags: c, linux, shell, gnu

I am trying to make my own linux shell. I have fixed bg command it is working with this code:

```
if (strcmp(worte[0], "bg")==0){
      pid_t pidnumber;
      pidnumber=atoi(worte[1]);
      printf("PID: %d", pidnumber);
      kill(pidnumber, SIGCONT);
      return 0;
    }
```

However, fg command is not working correctly. When I type "fg 12345" (12345 is process id), it puts that process into foreground, but I can not stop it with Ctrl-Z, also I can not use Ctrl-C. My code is following

```
if (strcmp(worte[0], "fg")==0){
      pid_t pidnumber;
      pidnumber=atoi(worte[1]);
      tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(pidnumber));
      waitpid(getpgid(pidnumber), NULL, WUNTRACED);
      tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(shellpid));

      return 0;
    }
```

In the code worte[0] refers fg and worte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrFdd.png) refers process id (ex:12345). How can I solve my problem thanks for helping. [Please look at the image to see my problem obviously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrFdd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the SIGTTOU.

```
pid_t pidnumber;
pidnumber=atoi(worte[1]);
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(pidnumber));
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
waitpid(getpgid(pidnumber), NULL, WUNTRACED);
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(shellpid));
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
```